# sorting a list of python tuples (first in descending order, then second element in ascending order

Tags: python

I'm trying to sort a list of tuples:

```
b=sorted(b, reverse = True)  

[(4, 'damme'), (3, 'van'), (3, 'name'), (3, 'is'), (2, 'my'), (2, 'hi'), (2, 'claude'), (2, 'bond'), (1, 'your'), (1, 'what'), (1, 'jean'), (1, 'james')]
```

I've got the sort by the first element sorted out, but I have no idea how to sort by 2nd element in lexigraphical order. Looked through the lambda function method on here but I could only see examples were both the first and second value were sorted in the same order (i.e. both ascending or both descending).

I'm trying to sort element 1 in descending order and then element 2 in ascending (alphabetical order).

Thanks!

Comment: basically `sorted(b, lambda t : -t[0],t[1])` that should work for this example

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Sorry for the dupe thread!

Comment: PS: to those who may come across this thread. This works: `sorted(b, key =lambda t : (-t[0],t[1]))`